# Why does select max(field) from table work so fast as compared to select min(field) from table, Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, select, max, oracle9i, min

i ran into the chance of running a select max statement in Oracle 9i and it ran very fast.

```
select max(id) from audit_log; 

select min(id) from audit_log;
```

However when running a select min, the query seems to hang and never return. This table has audit logs and some several hundred million records.

[Explain plan for select min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFFii.png)

[Explain plan for select max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0VeY.png)

Comment: Have you gotten an [explain plan](http://www.lorentzcenter.nl/awcourse/oracle/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) and/or a [trace](http://www.lorentzcenter.nl/awcourse/oracle/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm#1018)?

Comment: Hi Hank, i just did a quick explain plan, not sure if i have done it correctly.

Comment: I can't access the image from here. Can you cut'n'paste the textual content into your question?

Comment: @Jens Schauder They're identical, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Chin Boon They look like explain plans to me. Unfortunately, nothing jumps out at me to indicate why the `min` is behaving so strangely. I'd recommend doing the trace and running it through `TKPROF` to try to get more insight into the problem. I'm not an Oracle DBA, so I may not be able to help if it isn't obvious, but most DBAs will probably ask for this info anyway, so I hope it isn't a total waste of time.

Comment: I found this: http://momendba.blogspot.com/2008/07/min-and-max-functions-in-single-query.html which makes me wonder: is the query in question really just a vanilla min/max or are there other fields involved?

Comment: Or is the index a FBI or descending index? http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/index-full-scan-minmax-and-descending-index,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your max value is in memory. If it is incrementing quickly it is likely in memory all the time. If no one is accessing the min value it would have to be retrieved.

It could be that you are running into locking issues. Try changing the isolation level to see if that makes a difference.

It could be that your index is corrupt. Try rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason would be that column ID **does** have an index, but **can be null**. In that case rows with ID null **would not be in the index**. Hence min() cannot use the index on a nullable column.

...so chances are you just have to `alter table audit_log modify id not null;`

Or you might create a new composite index with a non-null column behind ID. That should work as well, because then every row would have an entry.

Comment: Wouldn't the explain_plans be different if this were the problem?

Comment: I thought so too, but a quick experiment showed that both min and max treat NULL in the same way, so I don't see how this explains the behavior described.